# Export opencv code in the form of a library

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, dll, qt-creator

I have written a very simple class in C++ using OpenCV.

```
#include "librarytestcreate.h"
#include<highgui.hpp>
using namespace cv;
LibraryTestCreate::LibraryTestCreate()
{
}
int LibraryTestCreate::countRows(char *src)
{
    Mat img = imread(src);
    return img.rows;
}
```

The header librarytestcreate.h is:-

```
#ifndef LIBRARYTESTCREATE_H
#define LIBRARYTESTCREATE_H

#include "librarytestcreate_global.h"

class LIBRARYTESTCREATESHARED_EXPORT LibraryTestCreate
{

public:
    LibraryTestCreate();
    int countRows(char *src);
};

#endif // LIBRARYTESTCREATE_H
```

The header librarytestcreate_global.h has defined LIBRARYTESTCREATESHARED_EXPORT according to [this](https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_create_a_library_with_Qt_and_use_it_in_an_application) link

I wish to export this class in a .dll file (in Windows) or a .so file (in Ubuntu) so that any user who does not have OpenCV installed in their system can use this function without having to install OpenCV. 
I have tried [this](https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_create_a_library_with_Qt_and_use_it_in_an_application) but I have a feeling I will have to configure the user will need to have OpenCV installed to use it. How should I approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you use OpenCV as dynamic library in your dynamic library project, then user of your dynamic library also must have OpenCV dynamic library when use your dynamic library. This is so, because your dynamic library depends on OpenCV dynamic library.

If you want that user of your dynamic library not needed in OpenCV dynamic library you must use OpenCV as static library in your dynamic library project or add all sources of OpenCV (that you need) straight in your project. I realy don't know, is it possible to use OpenCV as static library or reuse its code (I never use this library), maybe there is some license restrictions.

I think the best way for you is supply your dynamic library with OpenCV library in one installed package.

Answer (score 0):

As @Kirill Chernikov suggested, you'll need static libraries. Actually,
it's quite easy to build them for OpenCV. When you configure the build,
specify `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS`:

```
$ cmake $OTHER_CMAKE_PARAMETERS -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF $SOURCE_DIR
```

Of course you'll also need to set `$OTHER_CMAKE_PARAMETERS` and
`$SOURCE_DIR`, which are explained in ["Installation in Linux"](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html) and
["Installation in Windows"](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d52/tutorial_windows_install.html).

Then link the static libraries into your dynamic library.

As a sidenote, make sure *not* to expose OpenCV data types in the API of
your library. Otherwise things will get messy.